# Display data fromSQLite in TableLayout

Tags: java, android, sqlite, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

PLEASE help me...I'm very new to android development and now trying to retrieve `SQLite` Data Into `TableLayout`.  The program will retrieve the information which belongs to the name and finally display in `TableLayout`. But when I click the `button` in `WorkDetailsTable.java`, it crashed.

**DisplayData.java**

```
public class DisplayData extends AppCompatActivity {

    TableLayout table_layout;
    InfoAPI sqlcon;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.displaydata);
        MyDatabaseHelper db=new MyDatabaseHelper(this);
        InfoAPI I1=new InfoAPI(this);
        sqlcon=new InfoAPI(this);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        table_layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
        final String name1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name"); // pass from WorkDetailsTable.java
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (name1.equals("X X X")) ;
        {
            BuildTable(name1);
        }
        }

    private void BuildTable(String name)
    {

        sqlcon.open();
        Cursor c = sqlcon.readEntry(name); //refer to InfoAPI

        int rows = c.getCount();
        int cols = c.getColumnCount();

        c.moveToFirst();

        // outer for loop
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            row.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            // inner for loop
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tv.setTextSize(18);
                tv.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);

                tv.setText(c.getString(j));

                row.addView(tv);

            }

            c.moveToNext();

            table_layout.addView(row);

        }
        sqlcon.close();
    }

        }
```

**InfoAPI.java**

```
 public Cursor readEntry(String name) {

        String selectQuery = ("SELECT Weather,Date,Status FROM "+MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO+"WHERE Name= ?");
        database=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = database.query(MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO,new String[]{MyDatabaseHelper.ID,MyDatabaseHelper.Name,MyDatabaseHelper.Weather,MyDatabaseHelper.Date,MyDatabaseHelper.Status},MyDatabaseHelper.Name+"=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(name)}, null, null, null, null);

        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;

    }
```

**displaydata.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/weather"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Weather" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Date" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Status" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:shrinkColumns="*"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**LogCat Error**

```
10-10 08:52:04.691    6844-6844/com.example.project.project E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.project.project, PID: 6844
    java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
            at android.widget.TableLayout.mutateColumnsWidth(TableLayout.java:584)
            at android.widget.TableLayout.shrinkAndStretchColumns(TableLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.TableLayout.measureVertical(TableLayout.java:471)
            at android.widget.TableLayout.onMeasure(TableLayout.java:436)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
            at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1283)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
            at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:340)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
```

**Are the error came from InfoAPI? How to fix this? Any suggestions woukd be greatly appreciated.**

For your information, I have 5 data in my Info Table (id,name,weather,date,status), but I want retrieve weather,date and status only.

Comment: `java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero` says it all.

Comment: What does this mean? Sorry, I'm new bee

Comment: You are getting "ArithmeticException: divide by zero" because there are no view in table row.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this 2 lines in your `table layout`

```
  android:shrinkColumns="*"
            android:stretchColumns="*"
```